# NestJS and ask SDK service injection

Tags: nestjs, alexa-skills-kit, ask-sdk

I'm trying to build a custom Alexa webservice with nestjs.
From AlexaController if I try to call a service inside a RequestHandler, it doesn't work because the this. isn't available there ( if I try console.log(this) inside the requestHandler i see {canHandle, handle} ) and the server returns me that the service is undefined. This is my controller:

```js
import { Controller, HttpCode, Post, Req } from "@nestjs/common";
import {
  ErrorHandler,
  HandlerInput,
  RequestHandler,
  SkillBuilders,
} from "ask-sdk-core";
import { Response } from "ask-sdk-model";
import { Request } from "express";
import { MessagesService } from "src/services/messages/messages.service";

@Controller("alexa")
export class AlexaController {
  constructor(private myService: MessagesService) {}

  @Post()
  @HttpCode(200)
  async alexaSkill(@Req() req: Request) {
    let skill = SkillBuilders.custom()
      .addRequestHandlers(
        this.LaunchRequestHandler // welcome
      )
      .addErrorHandlers(this.ErrorHandler)
      .create();

    return skill
      .invoke(req.body)
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  LaunchRequestHandler: RequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput: HandlerInput): boolean {
      return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "LaunchRequest";
    },
    handle(handlerInput: HandlerInput): Response {
      const speechText = "Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say hello!";

      // here I want to call this.myService to do something.
      this.myService.something("hi Alexa");
      // it returns me this error: cannot call something of undefined

      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechText)
        .reprompt(speechText)
        .withSimpleCard("Hello World", speechText)
        .getResponse();
    },
  };

  ErrorHandler: ErrorHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput: HandlerInput, error: Error): boolean {
      return true;
    },
    handle(handlerInput: HandlerInput, error: Error): Response {
      console.log(`Error handled: ${error.message}`);

      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak("Sorry, I can't understand the command. Please say again.")
        .reprompt("Sorry, I can't understand the command. Please say again.")
        .getResponse();
    },
  };
}
```

This is my AlexaModule:

```js
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { MessagesService } from "src/services/messages/messages.service";
import { AlexaController } from "./alexa.controller";

@Module({
  controllers: [AlexaController],
  providers: [MessagesService],
})
export class AlexaModule {}
```

How can I make the service visible inside that RequestHandler ? Any suggestion ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` keyword in Javascript can refer to different things depending on the scope of where it's accessed. This is a common source of confusion for Javascript developers and there is a ton of content out there you can read about `this` scopes if you do a quick Google.

That being said, many of the common errors caused by this are now "solved" since the introduction of arrow functions in Javascript as they will automatically capture the `this` context from the outer scope which typically is the one you're after.

Try rewriting your handlers using arrow functions instead of using regular functions:

```js
LaunchRequestHandler: RequestHandler = {
        canHandle: (handlerInput: HandlerInput) => {
          return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "LaunchRequest";
        },
        handle: (handlerInput: HandlerInput) => {
          const speechText = "Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say hello!";
    
          this.myService.something("hi Alexa");
    
          return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .withSimpleCard("Hello World", speechText)
            .getResponse();
        },
      };
```